# "\/\/" disappearing during "Search and Replace" in Sublime 3

Tags: javascript, json, regex, sublimetext3

While pasting an URL into an JSON in Sublime 3 with the "Search and Replace" function, it seems like Sublime is formatting my URL and messing up the capitalization of the URL string

What I try to paste:

```
"href": "https:\/\/images.typeform.com\/images\/LoremIpsum"
```

What I get:

```
"href": "https://images.typeform.com/images/lOrEmIpSuM"
```

What can I do?

I tried this on both UltraEdit and Sublime 3, but the issue is the same

Answer (score 1):

Turn off regular expression by clicking the picture with `.*` in the upper left of the search and replace box.

If you leave Regex on, you will have to escape backslashes by using instead:

```
"href": "https:\\/\\/images.typeform.com\\/images\\/LOREMIPSUM"
```

Comment: just one more issue, it seems like the URL capitalization is also messed up

Comment: That does not happen for me. I don't know what would cause that.

Comment: If capitalization is changing in the replaced text you might want to double check that `Preserve Case` is not turned on; it's the button below the regex button.